# Create new transparent color in photoshop scripting

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to obtain a transparent color as background for an image with photoshop JSX scripts. The thing is that I can only create a `new SolidColor()`, and it won't accept 8 characters HEX colors that manage transparency...

```
    var bgColorHex = new SolidColor();
    bgColorHex.rgb.hexValue = options.bgColor;
    app.backgroundColor = bgColorHex;

    // ...

    app.activeDocument.selection.fill(bgColorHex);
```

Here I'd like to just use the `fill` function to fill with a transparent color instead of a solid color.

I can't find my way though their API, and [the script I'm starting from](https://github.com/bramus/photoshop-google-maps-tile-cutter) is old and not maintained anymore.

Comment: Can you not just add a new layer? - that'll be transparent. Unless of course you fill with a normal hex colour and then set the opacity of that layer to 0.

Comment: I can't really do that - everything is already merged in one layer (and I think the background color is set with `app.backgroundColor` (but I'm no photoshop script enthusiast to start with, so I'm only wondering...).

Comment: Can you make it easier and show an image of what you have and what you'd like it to be

Comment: If you open the file in Photoshop, what do you see in the layers palette. If there is only the Background then you cannot have transparency until you convert it to a layer.